# Making iPad app to support retina display

Tags: ios, ipad, retina-display

I have made an iPad app and it works cool. Problem is that my client want's to have retina high resolutions also supported in the app. So lets say We are using images with normal resolution in the app are of 15mb , so again we need to add high resolution each file. So it will increase the file. Is there any way where we can just place high res files only and they should work on both retina and non-retina .

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch image asset using `[UIImage imageWithName]` in that case, at the runtime appropriate image will be fetched for the device, i.e. if you'll use non-retina device it'll take 1x images and if you use retina device it'll use 2x images.

But, if you want you can fetch the file with  `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]` you'll be able to fetch that particular file.

You can also use [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/) tool to optimse the image without image quality loss.

Comment: but in this case we have to place images for both and it will increase size of the app package

Comment: You need not to add images for non-retina devices in your application, as you can use retina images for both devices.